# How do I delete rows with NAs and those that follow the NAs?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na

I have some data where I want to remove the NAs and the data that follows the NAs by the level of a factor.

Removing the NAs is easy:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D"), b=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1) ,c=c(4,5,3,2,1,5,NA,5,1,6,NA,2))
df
newdf<-df[complete.cases(df),];newdf
```

The final result should remove all of the rows for C and the final two rows of D.

Hope you can help.

Comment: With Base R you could do `df[!with(df, ave(c, a, FUN = function(x) cumsum(is.na(x)))),]`

Comment: Is there any reason that these functions would change the length of the factor column (a) but not the others? The functions do what I asked but R throws an 'arguments imply differing number of rows' error when I use the resultant data in a subsequent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic split-apply-combine in base R:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$a),function(x)x[cumsum(is.na(x$c))<1,]))
```

Here it is again, but in several lines:

```
split_df <- split(df, df$a)
apply_df <- lapply(split_df, function(x)x[cumsum(is.na(x$c))<1,])
combine_df <- do.call(rbind, apply_df)
```

The result:

```
> do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$a),function(x)x[cumsum(is.na(x$c))<1,]))
#    a b c
#A.1 A 0 4
#A.2 A 1 5
#A.3 A 0 3
#B.4 B 0 2
#B.5 B 0 1
#B.6 B 0 5
#D   D 0 6
```

Comment: So it's the `<1,` portion that removes the subsequent rows?

Comment: @ManassaMauler `is.na(x$c)` returns a vector of TRUE/FALSE of whether the values are NA. `cumsum` do the cumulative sum: hence effectively the first NA and everything that follows would be `1` or more (since `TRUE` coerces to 1 and `FALSE` to 0). Thus selecting whichever values are below 1 only keeps the values prior to the first NA.

Comment: Example: if `x$c` is `1 3 NA 2 NA 4 5`, then `is.na(x$c)` is `0 0 1 0 1 0 0` and `cumsum(is.na(x$c))` is `0 0 1 1 2 2 2`. Ultimately `cumsum(is.na(x$c)) < 1` will be `TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`, thus selecting only the first 2 rows when one uses it to subset `x`.

Answer (score 4):

We can try with data.table.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'a', get the cumulative sum of logical vector of NA elements in 'c' and check whether it is less than 1 to subset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  .SD[cumsum(is.na(c))<1], by= a]
```

Or a faster option with `.I` to return the row index of the logical vector and subset the rows.

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[cumsum(is.na(c)) < 1], by = a]$V1]
#   a b c
#1: A 0 4
#2: A 1 5
#3: A 0 3
#4: B 0 2
#5: B 0 1
#6: B 0 5
#7: D 0 6
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar solution in `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(!is.na(cumsum(c)))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: a [3]

       a     b     c
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1      A     0     4
2      A     1     5
3      A     0     3
4      B     0     2
5      B     0     1
6      B     0     5
7      D     0     6
```

If we take the cumulative sum of variable C, any values after the first `NA` will be converted to `NA`. Performing this at the group level allows us to remove `NA` rows and get the desired output.